# Cassandra Backup & Restore to another cluster

Tags: cassandra

We want to clone production cluster to test cluster.

On prod cluster, we did nodetool snapshot for keyspaces and restored on test cluster and used noedtool refresh and followed https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html

However, on test cluster, dev team record count does not match. We have about 25% less data in test cluster vs prod cluster. Prod cluster did not change 25% between time of snapshot and restore. There would be deviation of 1 to 2% but not 25%.
Prod cluster is 9 nodes so does test cluster and we have restored 1 node prod to 1 node in test cluster.
I am wondering what could be wrong here ? Any suggestions where should I look for issues ?

Comment: Did you try running repair on test cluster after data being loaded ?

Comment: Can you post the data load from `nodetool status` of both clusters?
When you say that you have a 25% difference, is it regarding size on disk? Or is it the count on the number of partitions/rows itself?
Did you increased the number of nodes in any of the clusters or did they always had six nodes? Did you run a `nodetool cleanup` after increasing the number of nodes?
How did you restore the data? Did you moved the SSTables back into their folders and run `nodetool refresh` or did you run `sstableloader`?
I know it's a lot of questions, but we need more info to troubleshoot. :)

Comment: Same number of nodes. 9 Nodes in prod and also in sandbox. There was no nodetool cleanup was run. Backup was taken using nodetool snapshot keyspace and copied snapshot directory content to sandbox in keyspace/table folder and then ran nodetool refresh. 25% is number of rows, it is just estimate that rows restored are no where close to production count.

Comment: I also noticed after snapshot files copied to sandbox and at that time contents of snapshot folder and sandbox kepspace tablename folder were same but as soon as we ran nodetool refresh on sandbox, contents , file names etc all change.

Comment: Yes, we ran repair too and data was still not same. We just now tried KillrVideo sample keyspace from prod to sandbox and samething . Count does not match.